# android : extract and encrypt header part of a file

Tags: android, encryption, filesystems

I am trying to do encryption / decryption of files. I could successfully encrypt the files. But when the file size is huge like video files, the algorithm takes very long time. To solve this, i want to encrypt only part of the file so that it cannot be open by any other app .

I am not sure if this is the right way to do it. SO please help me to find answers for :

Is this a feasible solution to encrypt only part of the file or only header ?
How can i get only header part ?

Is there a better solution for better performance?

Thanks in advance for your time and help

Comment: which library have you used for encryption? and did you get the answer for only header part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a feasible solution to encrypt only part of the file or only
>   header ? How can i get only header part ?

That depends on the content. In case of header files for video, it's likely that it can be recreated pretty easily (streaming video works with frames, as long as you can find those you can play the video). Of course, what constitutes a header depends completely on the file type.

> Is there a better solution for better performance?

Encrypt/decrypt on the fly. It's probably the IO that really should bug you, not so much the encryption time. You can use a high performance streaming cipher if performance of the encryption/decryption itself that's too slow. AES in CTR mode would be a good secure option, RC4 has better performance but comes with quite a few pitfalls.

Comment: Note that this is a straight answer, I won't go into the relative futility of trying to implement a DRM scheme.